# GA not tracking certain actions

Tags: php, magento, google-analytics

Our site is tracking CC and other transaction just fine, but has a problem with EFT transactions.

I have established that we are writing to the socket that is listening for GA calls with the correct information (compared it to another action that is being tracked correctly).

I need some help debugging the issue and was wondering if there was anywhere on the GA interface that I could see attempted and failed calls?

Answer (score 1):

The moment you see it in the interface it's by definition not a failed call so, no, but there is a debugger extension that writes errors (if any) to the [browser console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en).

If you do your tracking serverside (as you are talking about sockets) you could log the outgoing tracking calls to a file and send them to the debug endpoint by inserting the word "debug" after the hostname (so this would look something like [google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&tid=.....](https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&_v=j41d&a=335525335&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=file%3A%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fepierstorff%2FDesktop%2Ftest.html&dp=http%3A%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fepierstorff%2FDesktop%2Ftest.html&ul=de&de=windows-1252&dt=OFfline&sd=24-bit&sr=2560x1440&vp=2385x678&je=0&fl=21.0%20r0&_u=QEAAAIABI~&jid=2113413999&cid=761062822.1461745183&tid=UA-XXXXXX-X&_r=1&z=140208380)).

The debug endpoint will return a json response that points out missing  or invalid fields. Example response below:

```
{
  "hitParsingResult": [ {
    "valid": false,
    "parserMessage": [ {
      "messageType": "ERROR",
      "description": "The value provided for parameter 'tid' is invalid. Please see http://..... for details.",
      "messageCode": "VALUE_INVALID",
      "parameter": "tid"
    } ],
    "hit": "/debug/collect?v=1\u0026_v=j41d\u0026a=335525335\u0026t=pageview\u0026_s=1\u0026dl=file%3A%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fepierstorff%2FDesktop%2Ftest.html\u0026dp=http%3A%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fepierstorff%2FDesktop%2Ftest.html\u0026ul=de\u0026de=windows-1252\u0026dt=OFfline\u0026sd=24-bit\u0026sr=2560x1440\u0026vp=2385x678\u0026je=0\u0026fl=21.0%20r0\u0026_u=QEAAAIABI~\u0026jid=2113413999\u0026cid=761062822.1461745183\u0026tid=UA-XXXXXX-X\u0026_r=1\u0026z=140208380"
  } ],
  "parserMessage": [ {
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `debug` tip! I'll mark this as answered if it gives me any results :)